# proper term for a center of a set in a metric space

Tags: terminology, metric-spaces

I want to know if there is a proper term for the following kind of points, which I call it center(borrowed from graph theory).

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. $x\in X$ is a center of $A\subset X$ if $x\in A$ and 
$$
\sup_{a\in A} d(x,a) = \inf_{b\in A}  \sup_{a\in A} d(b,a) 
$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a [Chebyshev center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center) of the set (using indefinite article since such a point is not unique in general). Unfortunately, the beginning of the Wikipedia article is a mess: having nonempty interior is irrelevant, and the part after "alternatively" defines a different concept. But Google will confirm that the term Chebyshev center normally describes exactly the thing you introduced.